# How to remove events on fullCalendar based on className

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I was wondering if it was possible to remove events and render the fullcalendar again based on a className.

I have something that looks like this for now and it doesn't seem to work as planned.

```
if(bla = bla){
  displayCalData(myJsonData);   
 }

function displayCalData(json){
    //Define the cal ID to feed data too.
    var calendar = $('#calendar');
    calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents',myRemove);
    $.each(json, function(i, item) {
        //Create block render
        var displayText = item.displayName;

        var eventObject = {
                title: displayText,
                start: item.startDate,
                end : item.endDate,
                allDay:true,
                color: '#BABBBF',
                editable : false,
                className : "user_block"
        };   
        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventObject, true);
    }); 
}
function myRemove(event) {
    return "user_block" === event.className; // ensure your events have this custom class !
}
```

Also something to keep in mind, onLoad fullCalendar is also loaded with other event data from a seperate call.

Is there a way that I can remove all events on the calendar with the className "user_block" and re-render the calendar with the new data?

Thank you for reading and your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far to debug this problem? Have you tried adding `console.log()` messages to "myRemove" for example?

Comment: @Pointy Hey, yep what i've tried far has been attached on the code example above? and yes I have and it essentially returns function myRemove(event) {
    return "pending_block" === event.className;
}

Comment: No, what I mean is have you verified that that function is being **called**.

Comment: @Pointy Oh! yes the function is being called.

Comment: OK, well what exactly goes wrong? Are the events not removed? Have you logged what the event class names actually are, or checked to see whether they are explicitly equal to the value you're checking?

Comment: @Pointy inetesting doing something like this  calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', function(event) {
  return event.className == "user_block";
 }); seemed to solve the issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the function directly to removeEvents seem to do the trick

```
calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', function(event) {
    return event.className == "user_block";
});
```

Comment: Also you changed `===` to `==` - that's probably what *really* worked. I bet that the plugin maintains the "className" property as an *array* of strings, not just a single string.